# How to get the surrounding infomation with a location retrieve from GPS on android?

Tags: android

I checked the API for Maps, only to find for JavaScript.
Could anyone give me an android related example?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is [Google Places API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearches)